# wxVListBox with "dynamic" data

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a stream of data that I want to place into a container. This container will either be of fixed size or dynamically constrained to a certain size at runtime. The latter may be preferable.

When the container is full, the oldest data will be removed.

I want to display this data using a **wxVListBox** because I need full control of the display. However there is a problem: the calls to **OnDrawItem** are not atomic meaning that once the container is full, each call the **OnDrawItem** will be accessing moving data, the result will be a non-contiguous display with missing elements.

This is certainly true with any container with native array-like indexing, are required by **OnDrawItem**.

I can simulate array-like indexing in a **std::map** using iterator indexing, if the key is sequential integer, then all the items will be ordered and the map can be pruned quite easily, but that seems like an inefficient hack.

How can I solve this? Any other ideas or containers I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach seems to be to manage the full container state lazily within **OnDrawBackground**. That way the UI itself ensures the data remains static in the subsequent calls to **OnDrawItem**, using a deque as the container.